# UITableCell displaying improper conten

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiview

I am displaying a TabelCell that has images, button, UIView. When click the button it has to show UIView.

UIView is displaying but the problem is, if I click the button in first cell instead of displaying the UIView in the first cell, it is displaying the second cell or in some other cell. I don't know why this is happening.

The code is given below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"HomeTablecell";
  cell = (HomeTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  cell.vEdit.hidden=TRUE; //UIView hidden initially
  [cell.editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(EditButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //When this button is clicked cell.vEdit become visible
}

-(void)EditButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
  cell.vEdit.hidden=FALSE;
}
```

Comment: So every time you recycle a cell you add another target?

Comment: Yes each cell will have different conditions

Comment: But don't you think each cell should have only one target added?  Rather than adding one each time it's recycled?

Comment: Application requirement is not like that... each cell will have common items like name, profile image, time of post, main image, button for edit, delete and other button for reporting spam. Based on the conditions the functionality will change. I am trying different way now, don't know whether it will work or not. But going to try now

Comment: So why do you add a target each time the cell is recycled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for my question is FPPopover, when I use that control, the view is displaying exactly in the position I wanted

https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover/

Answer (score -1):

1: make sure the cell is referenced correctly(for instance I added tag to the button clicked)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"HomeTablecell";
  cell = (HomeTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
  cell.vEdit.hidden=YES; //UIView hidden initially
   cell.editBUtton.tag = indexPath.row //suppose has 1 section, you can customise the tag rule based on section/row
  [cell.editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(EditButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //When this button is clicked cell.vEdit become visible
}

-(void)EditButtonClicked:(UIButton*)sender
{
HomeTableCell* theCell = self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:sender.tag inSection:0];
  theCell.vEdit.hidden =NO;
}
```

2: Make sure UIView is hidden in your customised cell class for reused cell

```
//Your cell class
- (void)prepareForReuse {
    [super prepareForReuse];
    self.vEdit.hidden=YES;
}
```

Comment: So, why do you add a new target each time the cell is recycled?

Comment: do you have any solution? @HotLicks